# iOS: adding Admob ads into app giving an error

Tags: ios, admob

My app was successfully running on both simulator and physical device. After adding AdMob into my app by following the [instruction in this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1bFU46D-4t8) , however, the app gives an error when building. I have tried several hours to look for the solution to this error, but could not find it. Do you have any suggestion for this? Thank you

```
ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate in /Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/playSound-dxljeytitbiylehchltjsxksklbh/Build/Intermediates/playSound.build/Debug-iphoneos/playSound.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AppDelegate-B7F42A95B6FCD25F.o and /Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/playSound-dxljeytitbiylehchltjsxksklbh/Build/Intermediates/playSound.build/Debug-iphoneos/playSound.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AppDelegate-B9769CE7F9C30755.o for architecture armv7
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

**Update:**

Even I have not modified any code in my app, just add all the folder of 'GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS-6.1.4' in my project explorer as in the video, it then produces the error immediately. I am using xCode 4.2

Comment: Looks as if you suddenly got two classes called AppDelegate within your project. Maybe you accidentially imported the implementation file of that class instead of the header file? (check all your `#import` statements for their file-suffix to be `.h`).

Comment: I've checked the code thoroughly, all are imported properly

Comment: Have you got your app delegate added in the compile sources build phase twice? (I'm assuming it's not anything obvious like you've made two different classes called `AppDelegate` :)

Comment: I find out that, even I have not modified any code in my app, just add all the folder of 'GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS-6.1.4' in my project explorer as in the video, it then produces the error immediately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be because 6.1.4 also comes packaged with a Google Analytics xcode project. Try making sure that you remove everything under the 'Add-ons' folder from being referenced in your project (unless you are using it).

Comment: do you mean that not adding the folder `Add-ons` into project? I do not need Google Analytics

Comment: Amazingly, I remove the `Add-ons` folder, it works immediately. I took me almost 10 hours on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple entries `AppDelegate` under `Targets-Compiled Sources`. Check it and ensure there is only one in `Compiled Sources`.

Comment: It is true that there are two AppDelegate under Targets-Compiled Sources. I removed one, but it is still not working.

Comment: It is strange, my app has just a UIlabel with "Hello World", working perfectly. But when adding the folder, `GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS-6.1.4`, it gives error above. Does the package has bug?